# Show/hide table view cell using UISwitch

Tags: swift, uitableview, uiswitch

I want to use `UISwitch` to show/hide a tableViewCell in a dynamic table view. 
UISwitch is defined in a class of `UITableViewCell.

```
@IBOutlet weak var switchState: UISwitch!
```

And in the another file I want say if this switch is ON, the number of rows will be 5 otherwise it should be 4

```
func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, numberOfRowsInSection section: Int) -> Int {
    let test = PopupViewCell()
    if test.switchState?.isOn == true {
        detailsTableView.reloadData()
        return 5
    } else {
        return 4
    }
}
```

But it's not working, and it always read `return 4. 
I also test it:

```
func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, numberOfRowsInSection section: Int) -> Int {
    let test = PopupViewCell()
    if test.switchState.isOn {
        detailsTableView.reloadData()
        return 5
    } else {
        return 4
    }
}
```

But I will get this error:

```
Thread 1: Fatal error: Unexpectedly found nil while unwrapping an Optional value
```

I am not sure that I have to use some action function before this process or not, I will be appreciated if someone can help me on that.

Comment: Cells aren't supposed to save their data source. You have to have separate data source array with your objects which says something like: object 1 - is visible, object 2 - isn't, ... and then in set outlets values depending on object's properties. Also reason of your error is, that you're just initializing your cell and your outlets aren't connected correctly because you're initializing it wrong. Dynamic cells should be dequeued.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The most beginner friendly way to do it is with a delegate.  When the Switch cell detects a `.valueChanged` event it should forward this to the delegate.  The delegate in turn updates its model of whether or not to show the switch and then reloads the `tableView`.

Here is a Playground example:

```
import UIKit
import PlaygroundSupport

protocol SwitchDelegate: class {
    func toggle(isOn: Bool)
}

class SwitchCell: UITableViewCell {
    private lazy var switchControl: UISwitch = {
        let switchControl = UISwitch()
        contentView.addSubview(switchControl)
        switchControl.translatesAutoresizingMaskIntoConstraints = false
        switchControl.leadingAnchor.constraint(equalTo: contentView.leadingAnchor, constant: 12).isActive = true
        switchControl.centerYAnchor.constraint(equalTo: contentView.centerYAnchor).isActive = true
        switchControl.addTarget(self, action: #selector(toggleSwitch(_:)), for: .valueChanged)
        return switchControl
    }()
    private weak var delegate: SwitchDelegate?
    override func awakeFromNib() {
        super.awakeFromNib()

    }
    func configure(isOn: Bool, delegate: SwitchDelegate) {
        switchControl.isOn = isOn
        self.delegate = delegate
    }
    @objc private func toggleSwitch(_ sender: UISwitch) {
        delegate?.toggle(isOn: sender.isOn)
    }
}

class ViewController: UITableViewController {
    private let data = (0..<5).map { $0 + 1 }
    private var isOn = true
    override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()
        tableView.register(UITableViewCell.self, forCellReuseIdentifier: String(describing: UITableViewCell.self))
    }
    override func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, numberOfRowsInSection section: Int) -> Int {
        return data.count + (isOn ? 1 : 0)
    }
    override func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, cellForRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> UITableViewCell {
        if isOn && indexPath.row == 0 {
            let switchCell = SwitchCell(style: .default, reuseIdentifier: String(describing: SwitchCell.self))
            switchCell.configure(isOn: isOn, delegate: self)
            return switchCell
        } else {
            let cell = tableView.dequeueReusableCell(withIdentifier: String(describing: UITableViewCell.self), for: indexPath)
            let dataIndex = indexPath.row - (isOn ? 1 : 0)
            cell.textLabel?.text = String(describing: data[dataIndex])
            return cell
        }
    }
}

extension ViewController: SwitchDelegate {
    func toggle(isOn: Bool) {
        self.isOn = isOn
        tableView.reloadData()
    }
}

PlaygroundPage.current.liveView = ViewController()
```

Comment: I prefer closures to delegates

Comment: Thank you so much for your help Josh, I think it's my answer. Just one thing, I implemented your code in my project, there is just a problem, you create a UISwitch programmatically and add 'addTarget' inside its variable, but since I have defined the UISwitch by outlet, I dont understand  how I can use addTarget with an outlet UISwitch. Could you help me on that?

Comment: To add the target from a nib or storyboard you ctrl+drag from the button into the code and create and IBAction.  Alternatively, you can still do it in code just as I do above even if you make the button in the storyboard to begin with. ( in that case put the add target statement in viewDidLoad or in a didSet on your IBOutlet -- either one will work).